# How to retrieve TFS file user has checked out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

We had a user that left the company abruptly and has checked out files under their name. We need these files and their changes that were made to the file. How can we get them in TFS?

Comment: check file's history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they put their changes in a shelveset, anyone should be able to pull the shelveset and check the changes in permanently. If they didn't, the modified files are wherever their workspace is (was?) and they'd have to be retrieved from there. If you have a TFS administrator, they might be able to get at the workspace definition(s) for that user and back in to a check-out location.

Where I work, workstations are usually imaged when someone resigns so if we need to get at their work it's available for six months or so even if their system gets wiped.